Mint Nft solana RUST langauge
I wrote this code but it isnt working :) Im confused, I dont know what problem with it
**
**Here is example of transaction what i need ****https://solscan.io/tx/4AxMcvuLZpRhd1sCK76idD8T9BKifaTwaeC8rHwtYZG6YWijC7vk2yQziES1hscDijEityGRVYHw6ugtfztkzaMd
**
Here error what i have now**
Payer pubkey: 5RCvKosYvPzDxEd3fwvugvtmac51EJuCSb4WKqHgJdDG
Mint account pubkey: same
Fee payer pubkey: same
Recipient pubkey: 6xv1JyHpS8DrbqWu56emEnssUEYt8HVQyxLJc4Ry7P4T
ERROR: Error { request: Some(SendTransaction), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError { code: -32002, message: "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: custom program error: 0xbbf", data: SendTransactionPreflightFailure(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(InstructionError(2, Custom(3007))), logs: Some(["Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]", "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success", "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]", "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success", "Program F9SixdqdmEBP5kprp2gZPZNeMmfHJRCTMFjN22dx3akf invoke [1]", "Program log: Instruction: MintCv3", "Program log: AnchorError caused by account: machine. Error Code: AccountOwnedByWrongProgram. Error Number: 3007. Error Message: The given account is owned by a different program than expected.", "Program log: Left:", "Program log: 11111111111111111111111111111111", "Program log: Right:", "Program log: F9SixdqdmEBP5kprp2gZPZNeMmfHJRCTMFjN22dx3akf", "Program F9SixdqdmEBP5kprp2gZPZNeMmfHJRCTMFjN22dx3akf consumed 4371 of 249701 compute units", "Program F9SixdqdmEBP5kprp2gZPZNeMmfHJRCTMFjN22dx3akf failed: custom program error: 0xbbf"]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(4671), return_data: None, inner_instructions: None }) })
**
Here my code**
use solana_client::rpc_client::RpcClient;  // Import Solana RPC client
use solana_sdk::{
    pubkey::Pubkey,
    signature::{Keypair, Signer},
    transaction::Transaction,
    system_instruction,
};
use solana_program::instruction::{AccountMeta, Instruction};  // Import types for program instructions
use std::str::FromStr;  // Import FromStr function for string-to-data type conversions
use bs58;  // Import for working with Base58 encoding
use hex;  // Import for working with hexadecimal encoding

const COMPUTE_BUDGET_PROGRAM_ID: &str = "ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111";  // Program ID for compute budget management
const MINT_PROGRAM_ID: &str = "F9SixdqdmEBP5kprp2gZPZNeMmfHJRCTMFjN22dx3akf";  // Program ID for NFT minting

fn keypair_from_base58(base58_str: &str) -> Result<Keypair, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    println!("Trying to decode base58 key: {}", base58_str);
    let bytes = bs58::decode(base58_str).into_vec()?;  // Decode key from Base58
    println!("Decoded bytes: {:?}", bytes);
    if bytes.len() != 64 {
        return Err("Decoded byte array length is not 64".into());  // Check decoded byte array length
    }
    let keypair = Keypair::from_bytes(&bytes)?;  // Create Keypair from decoded bytes
    Ok(keypair)
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let private_key_str = "YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY_HERE";
    let keypair = keypair_from_base58(private_key_str)?;  // Get Keypair from Base58 string

    let payer_pubkey = keypair.pubkey();  // Get the payer's public key
    let mint_account_pubkey = payer_pubkey;  // Use the public key for minting
    let fee_payer_pubkey = payer_pubkey;  // Use the public key for transaction fees
    let recipient_pubkey_str = "6xv1JyHpS8DrbqWu56emEnssUEYt8HVQyxLJc4Ry7P4T";
    let recipient_pubkey = Pubkey::from_str(recipient_pubkey_str)?;  // Get recipient's public key

    println!("Payer pubkey: {}", payer_pubkey);  // Print payer's public key
    println!("Mint account pubkey: {}", mint_account_pubkey);  // Print mint account public key
    println!("Fee payer pubkey: {}", fee_payer_pubkey);  // Print fee payer's public key
    println!("Recipient pubkey: {}", recipient_pubkey_str);  // Print recipient's public key

    let rpc_url = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com";  // Solana RPC server URL
    let rpc_client = RpcClient::new(rpc_url.to_string());  // Create new RPC client

    // Check payer's balance
    let balance = rpc_client.get_balance(&payer_pubkey)?;  // Get payer's balance
    println!("Balance: {}", balance);

    if balance == 0 {
        println!("Error: The account does not have enough SOL to cover transaction fees.");
        return Ok(());  // Check if balance is sufficient for transaction fees
    }

    let recent_blockhash = rpc_client.get_latest_blockhash()?;  // Get the latest blockhash

    let compute_budget_program_id = Pubkey::from_str(COMPUTE_BUDGET_PROGRAM_ID)?;  // Convert compute budget program ID
    let mint_program_id = Pubkey::from_str(MINT_PROGRAM_ID)?;  // Convert minting program ID

    // Instruction to set compute unit price and limit
    let set_compute_unit_price_instruction = Instruction {
        program_id: compute_budget_program_id,
        accounts: vec![AccountMeta::new(fee_payer_pubkey, true)],  // Pass fee payer's public key as account
        data: hex::decode("037811010000000000")?,  // Data for instruction
    };

    let set_compute_unit_limit_instruction = Instruction {
        program_id: compute_budget_program_id,
        accounts: vec![AccountMeta::new(fee_payer_pubkey, true)],  // Pass fee payer's public key as account
        data: hex::decode("0291d00300")?,  // Data for instruction
    };

    // Instruction to mint NFT
    let mint_instruction = Instruction {
        program_id: mint_program_id,
        accounts: vec![
            AccountMeta::new(payer_pubkey, true),  // Payer's public key
            AccountMeta::new(mint_account_pubkey, true),  // Mint account public key
            AccountMeta::new(recipient_pubkey, false),  // Recipient's public key (not mutable)
        ],
        data: hex::decode("38a6524fe800f61100000000c0d8a7000000000001000000000100")?,  // Data for instruction
    };

    // Create transaction with specified fee payer
    let transaction = Transaction::new_signed_with_payer(
        &[  // Array of instructions for the transaction
            set_compute_unit_price_instruction,
            set_compute_unit_limit_instruction,
            mint_instruction,
        ],
        Some(&fee_payer_pubkey),  // Specify fee payer's public key
        &[&keypair],  // Array of signatures
        recent_blockhash,  // Latest blockhash
    );

    // Send and confirm transaction
    println!("Sending transaction...");
    let signature = rpc_client.send_and_confirm_transaction(&transaction)?;  // Send transaction and get signature
    println!("Transaction successful with signature: {}", signature);  // Print successful transaction signature

    Ok(())  // Return successful result
}
```
`


<sub>*if you want more information, please tell me in comments*</sub>

Problem int PROGRAM_ID i think, not with PubKey, ofrotionaluy with logic of my code, but i didnt see....

when i try this program_id - noopb9bkMVfRPU8AsbpTUg8AQkHtKwMYZiFUjNRtMmV Its working (https://solscan.io/tx/5bWvTWnbgDFv7yrGM7UyLMcDuMxtYfce7psVb3adkSWRvuJknHa212Dv2CXxZU2DfQDRpu2yEYynvRNAp64qJB2d), but i need all working cycle of minting NFT, not succses only one program)


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
